# Should I delete my answer after finding a similar answer on a SuperUser sister site?

Tags: discussion, answers

I apology if this question has already been answered in any form.

Today, I answered this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1564696/archive-all-the-urls-of-a-website-to-waybackmachine-https-web-archive-org). I knew the answer will be found in archive.org website, so went there, copied the relevant information and posted my answer. Then, the OP commented that there will be a ton of pages to copy individually. I then decided to search if there will be possible alternatives. One of the first search link was from [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/how-to-archive-the-whole-website). One of the answers there is from the same source than mine, with the most upvoted one being an alternative.

A few minutes ago, I edited my answer and added the link to the Web Application's question. Should I delete my answer due to being sourced from page that is already answered on a sister site of SuperUser?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just vote to migrate the question to Web Applications?  Honestly, somebody already voted to migrate it, you probably should have done so instead of answering it.

Comment: @Ramhound I did not notice that someone voted for the question to be migrated when I answered.

Comment: I have just checking the time the question was posted and when I answered (not the edit). is around 9mn.

Comment: I am suggesting the question should have never been answered and just migrated to Web Applications.

Comment: I understand, thanks.